# Filling a label with a string signature method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following simple code which will "format" two given dateTime variables.

```
DateTime lastYear = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1); 
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(annuualDateFormatter(lastYear, now));

string annuualDateFormatter(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return "from " + startDate +
              " to " + endDate; 
}
```

I was wondering if the following is possible in asp.net webforms(gridview), the following code obviously is a simple console appplication

```
some_label.text = annuualDateFormatter(lastYear, now);
```

or if there's another way to do that, as I pretty sure I do not have console.write over there:)

thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is entirely possible in ASP.Net. A textbox/label control's text property can be set with the formatted datetimes as you did in the second code example. Lastly, while you are correct that console.write is not readily available, you could use debug.write as a fair substitute assuming you are coding with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For general format of a datetime, then you can do this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
```

So, code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime lastYear = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        string sFMT2 = "dddd MMMM dd, yyyy";  // Wednesday November 16, 2022

        Label1.Text = annuualDateFormatter(lastYear, now);            
        Label2.Text = annuualDateFormatter(lastYear, now, sFMT2);
    }

    string annuualDateFormatter(DateTime startDate,
                                DateTime endDate,
                                string sFMT = "MMM dd, yyyy")  // default Nov 16, 2022
    {
        return "from " + startDate.ToString(sFMT) +
                " to " + endDate.ToString(sFMT);

    }
```

Results:

[image]

However, in a grid view, while you "can" format with colors or whatever for each column?

GV has built in date formatters.

So, say this GV - we have a datetime column of "first flight", but that means the time portion in the database will be 00:00:00.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    CssClass="table" Width="50%" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"        />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine"  HeaderText="Engine"         />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust"  HeaderText="Thrust (lbs)"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstFlight" HeaderText="First Flight"
              ItemStyle-Width="100"    />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"    />
        <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="132">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And code behind to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Fighters ORDER BY Thrust";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And we see/get this:

[image]

but, note the date in above, it has no format, so we see the "zero" time portion.

So, you can add/use date formatting one of two ways.

This:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FirstFlight" HeaderText="First Flight"
    DataFormatString ="{0:MM dd yyyy}" ItemStyle-Width="100"    />
```

And we see/get this:

[image]

Of course, often we use a templated field/control in a GV, such as say a check box, or even a plane jane label.

So, say we have this markup (using a plain jane lable control in the GV), then note how you can just "tack on" the format to the eval expression like this:

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust"  HeaderText="Thrust (lbs)"   />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Flight">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("FirstFlight", "{0:MMM dd yyyy}")  %>' >
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"    />
```

Now, in above, we do have the "thrust" in lbs, so we probably should format that number at least with a "," (1000 Seperator).

So, now this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thrust (lbs)">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTHURST" runat="server"                         
                    Text='<%# Eval("Thrust", "{0:N0}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And we get this:

[image]

And thus again, we get/see this:

Comment: Appreciate your reply, thanks alot